# Macroscopic Maxwell Lagrangian

Tags: field-theory, maxwell-equations

We know that the microscopic Maxwell Lagrangian (density) with source $J^\mu$

$$
\mathcal{L}
=
-\frac{1}{4}
F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}
+
A_\mu J^\mu
$$

with the antisymmetric field-strength tensor

$$
F^{\mu\nu}
=
\partial^\mu A^\nu
-
\partial^\nu A^\mu
$$

recovers the microscopic Maxwell equations when we consider the equation of motion

$$
\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu}=J^\nu
$$

and convert the tensor equations to vector equations using, e.g., $E^i=F^{0i}$.

The macroscopic Maxwell equations were developed as a coarse-grained, i.e., macroscopic, version of the microscopic Maxwell equations, which account for polarization and magnetization effects of electromagnetic fields in macroscopic media.
In macroscopic media, it is common to relate the electromagnetic field amplitudes by the refractive index which in general can be space- and time-dependent $n(\boldsymbol{x},t)$.

**Has there been any attempts to formulate a macroscopic Maxwell Lagrangian?**

If yes, what form does such a macroscopic Maxwell Lagrangian have? What books or articles discuss a field-theoretic approach to macroscopic electromagnetism?

Comment: Have a look at this wikipedia-page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_formulation_of_classical_electromagnetism#Covariant_objects_in_matter Especially part 5 "Covariant objects in matter", part 6 "Maxwell's equations in matter" and the last formula in part 7 "Lagrangian for classical electrodynamics"

Comment: @Udalricus.S. Hi, thanks these are indeed helpful but I guess more suited for someone already common to the topic. I found https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Quantum-Electrodynamics-in-a-Linear-Absorptive-Amooshahi/8c0672226fea03f9439a2fa42540bd03c05da7ad to discuss some of the approaches and problems of incorporating macroscopic medias into an effective Lagrangian.